# Will I be able to use Java 6 with Android-L

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, java-7, java-6

In order to use the developer preview of Android-L it's [necessary](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html) to use Java 7. But will I be able to use Java 6 with the official release of Android-L?

Comment: This question will be meaningless in a year. We cannot guess what Google will deliver. For such speculations, use other forums.

Comment: My speculation: possibly no, because Android L might use Java 7's feature extensively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO -- if you are developing, use the latest supported environment (currently that is Android Studio 1.0 with Java 7 or Java 8 (oracle will drop support of Java 7 in April of next year).

Do not stay with outdated, unsupported versions of Java ... no need to add problems to your day.